# How did my WPF control become a FocusScope?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-6.0

I have a WPF desktop app `TargetFramework = net6.0-windows10.0.17763.0`. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/focus-overview#logical-focus) say

> An element can be turned into a focus scope in Extensible Application Markup Language (XAML) by setting the FocusManager attached property IsFocusScope to true. In code, an element can be turned into a focus scope by calling SetIsFocusScope.
>
> ...
>
> Classes in WPF which are focus scopes by default are Window, MenuItem, ToolBar, and ContextMenu.

I have a window containing a few controls in which I am getting unexpected focus behaviour. As a test I added this in the .xaml:

```
<TextBox GotFocus="UIElement_OnGotFocus" />
```

And in the codebehind:

```
private void UIElement_OnGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var c = (Control)sender;
    var fs = (Control)FocusManager.GetFocusScope(c);
    Console.WriteLine(fs);
}
```

To my surprise, the logged line says `MyControls.CustomView`, which is a custom control that inherits directly from `UserControl`.

However I am certain of the following: nowhere in the codebase do we set `IsFocusScope` or call `SetIsFocusScope`. The custom control does not inherit from the four classes mentioned in the Microsoft docs.

A control has become a focus scope but not via any of the documented routes. How can this happen? Can WPF internally call `SetIsFocusScope` on a user control?

Comment: There are two ways to get a complete minimal example. 1. Strip the current code 2. Build from scratch - Choose the way which is faster, but it is up to you or it is too "massive and complicated so I can't provide" an answer. BTW In a lot of cases when building the example you will solve the problem by yourself

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Unfortunately technique 1 could take many days and still might not yield conclusive results. And technique 2 is not guaranteed to produce the same results.

I disagree that this question cannot be tackled in its current state. Perhaps this statement is true: 'WPF internally calls SetIsFocusScope in the following undocumented circumstances...'. Someone who knows that, perhaps who has encountered this scenario themselves, can answer the question.

Comment: I have rephrased the question slightly and removed the part about 'massive and complicated' since I believe it is not relevant.

Comment: Well, then you should add at minimum more details of the version you are using. .net framework, .net core, .net and what specific version and add that as a tag to the question

Comment: @SirRufo thanks -- version details added.

Comment: ehm, which .net-core version? There are currently 11 channels having multiple releases on each https://versionsof.net/core/

Comment: .NET Core 6.0 as it says at the top of the question now. Is there also a version-specific tag I should use? I don't get prompted by one when adding tags.

Comment: I've got .NET 6.0.15 which doesn't seem to exist yet on the link you sent. [Only just released](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/march-2023-updates/). I think it's reasonable to assume this question applies to earlier versions too according to the release notes, and most releases in the 6.0 series being security updates only.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252767/discussion-between-hugh-w-and-sir-rufo).

Comment: Whoever voted to close, can you provide me on more detail why? I got some specific feedback from @SirRufo which I addressed. What else is lacking?

Comment: Note to anyone else with this problem: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/windows/Input/FocusManager.cs,414 looks incriminating,.

Comment: Also: https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/7671